# Перенос файлов скриптом и с сохранением предыдущего каталога

Tags: bash, find

Тут созрела идея для архивирования фалов с одного сервера на другой в centos, но пока что на тестовом сервере не пойму как это сделать.
На тестовом сервере существует папка **home/dir/lib/** в ней куча папок с названиями типа **dom les zal**, а уже в этих папках лежат структурированные по дате папки типа **dom_11.2020** и **dom_12.2020** и так во всех, задача состоит в том чтобы перенести папки только с окончанием **11.2020**, но чтобы в конечной точке создалась папка и ложилось всё в нужную папку типа **dom_11.2020** в папку **dom**, а **les_11.2020** в **les** и так далее, изначально в конечной точке не создано папок **dom les** и т.д.
Моя первая попытка командой `find . -name "*11.2020" -exec mv {} /home/test_dir \;` переносятся только конечные папки в каталог **/home/test_dir**.

Далее же я хочу осуществить перенос через scp на другой сервер и в случае удачного выполнения удалить исходники, запихать всё это в баш скрипт и подставить вместо ***11.2020** аргумент который будет запрашиваться при запуске скрипта.
Помогите мне разобраться как осуществить копирование или перенос с сохранением каталога выше найденного значения, далее я буду дополнять архив папками с окончанием **12.2020**, архивировать файлы в архиваторами мне не надо.

Comment: `$ tar -c ... | ssh ... tar -x -d ...`

Comment: это не решает мою проблему...

Comment: полностью решает: сохраняется структура каталогов.

Comment: вы предлагаете сделать так `tar -c "архив" | ssh "удаленный сервер" tar -x -d "каталог на удалённом сервере для архивации`, а как же выборка и автоматизация? и запихивать в .tar мне нет необходимости.

Comment: `$ cd home/dir/lib && tar -c */*11.2020 | ssh ...`